# Correct use of L'Hospital's rule?

Tags: limits

I'm trying to determine the following limit:

$$\lim_{t\rightarrow0}\frac{\delta\theta t(1-t)^{-\theta-1}}{(1-t)^{-\theta}-1} \ ,$$

where $\theta \geq 0$ and $\delta \geq 1$.

Substituting $t = 0$, I get

$$\frac{\delta\theta\cdot0\cdot1^{-\theta-1}}{1^{-\theta}-1} = \frac{0}{0}$$

that is an indeterminate form. Applying L'Hospital's rule I have

$$\lim_{t\rightarrow0}\frac{\delta\theta t(1-t)^{-\theta-1}}{(1-t)^{-\theta}-1} \  = \lim_{t\rightarrow0}\frac{\delta\theta(1-t)^{-\theta-1}-\delta\theta t(-\theta-1)(1-t)^{-\theta-2}}{(-1)(-\theta)(1-t)^{-\theta-1}} = \frac{\delta\theta}{\theta} = \delta \ .$$

Is this correct? The solution to the actual problem I need this limit for seems to agree with it.

Comment: I get $\delta\theta(1-t)^{-\theta-1}-\delta\theta t(-\theta-1)(1-t)^{-\theta-2}$ for the upper part, but that doesn't affect the final result.

Comment: Thanks, I've edited the question to fix the sign error.

Comment: Other than that it is okay :)

Comment: Note that since the $(1-t)^{-\theta -1}$ approaches $1$, you could have found the limit of $\frac{\delta\theta t}{(1-t)^{-\theta}-1}$, and multiplied the answer by $1$. Simpler differentiation.  (The limit is indeed $\delta$.)

Answer (score 1):

This is not an answer but it is too long for a comment.

You perfectly did the job using L'Hopital. You also could have done the same using Taylor expansion which can provide you some more information.

Using the binomial theorem, the numerator would be $$\delta  \theta  t+t^2 \left(\delta  \theta ^2+\delta  \theta
   \right)+O\left(t^3\right)$$ and the denominator $$\theta  t+\frac{1}{2} \left(\theta ^2+\theta \right) t^2+O\left(t^3\right)$$ Performing the long division, the expression then write $$\delta +\frac{1}{2} \delta  (\theta +1) t+O\left(t^2\right)$$

Answer (score 0):

for the denominator i have got $$\delta\,\theta\, \left( 1-t \right) ^{-\theta-1}-{\frac {\delta\,
\theta\,t \left( 1-t \right) ^{-\theta-1} \left( -\theta-1 \right) }{1
-t}}
$$ and for the numerator
$${\frac { \left( 1-t \right) ^{-\theta}\theta}{1-t}}$$
simplifying this we obtain
$$-{\frac { \left( t\theta+1 \right) \delta}{-1+t}}$$

Comment: sorry for $t->0$ we get $\delta$ as the searched limit